# ESP32 > using esp_console + argtable3 in a C++ project

Tags: c++, esp32

I'am developping a C++ project on an ESP32.
I'd like to use esp_console + argtable3 (C libraries) in it.
I'm trying to use argtable3 in my members functions.
To do so, I'm creating callback functions to my members functions with a global pointer.
I'm sure my class is going to be instanced only once so I assume it's ok to create callback functions.

The problem is that argtable isn't giving me back the parameters entered by the user.
It checks for them successfully (number of args and their type) but the data it gives me back is random.
I've tested my code outside of members functions and it works well. But I want to use it inside members functions to access other parts of my object.
Here is my code :

```
// Pointer for my callback functions
MyClass * _callback;

struct arg_int *argInt;
struct arg_end *endPage;

// My callback function (GLOBAL)
int _setInt(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return _callback->setInt(argc, argv);
}

// Tab of struct for argtable lib (GLOBAL)
void *setInt_argtable[] =
{
    argInt = arg_int1(NULL, NULL, "<0-12>", "Integer argument"),
    endInt = arg_end(10)
};

// Function I'm calling back
int MyClass::setInt(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nerrors = arg_parse(argc,argv,setInt_argtable);
    if (nerrors > 0)
    {
        arg_print_errors(stdout, endPage, "myprog");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);                // argc gives the correct number of args
    printf("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);          // argv[0] gives the correct command name
    printf("argv[1] = %s\n", argv[1]);          // argv[1] gives the correct value
    printf("argInt->ival[0] = %d\n", argInt->ival[0]);  // argInt->ival[0] gives random value
    return 0;
}

void MyClass::main(void)
{
    // Callback pointer initialisation
    _callback = this;

    /* Initializing the console */
    esp_console_config_t console_config
    {
        256,
        8,
        atoi(LOG_COLOR_CYAN),
        0
    };
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_console_init(&console_config) );

    /* Configure linenoise line completion library */
    /* Enable multiline editing. If not set, long commands will scroll within
    * single line.
    */
    linenoiseSetMultiLine(1);

    /* Tell linenoise where to get command completions and hints */
    linenoiseSetCompletionCallback(&esp_console_get_completion);
    linenoiseSetHintsCallback((linenoiseHintsCallback*) &esp_console_get_hint);

    /* Set command history size */
    linenoiseHistorySetMaxLen(100);


    esp_console_register_help_command();

    //
    // Feeding my console with argtable parameters
    //

    esp_console_cmd_t consoleCmd;
    consoleCmd.command  = "setInt";
    consoleCmd.func     = &_setInt;
    consoleCmd.help     = "Trying to set a integer argument";
    consoleCmd.argtable = setInt_argtable;
    esp_console_cmd_register(&consoleCmd);

    /* Main loop */
    while(true)
    {
        // Getting command from user
    }
}
```

Is my approach of using callback member function good ?
Any idea of what is my problem and how I could solve it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

After being copying/pasting very simple sample codes found on internet, I finally found what was the problem :

I was including `<argtable3/argtable3.h>` after `"myclass.h"`

It took me almost 2 days for a dumb error...

But if somebody has an explanation about why the inclusion order was allowing me to compile the program but making a "corrupted" binary, feel free to answer !